# How do I undo UAC admin permission elevation for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: windows-10, uac

I long-ago set devenv.exe to run with elevated privileges (aka run as administrator) so I could run web apps locally, in IIS, and devenv could access the local IIS metabase without issue.

I did that by running the Troubleshoot Compatibility wizard on devenv.exe.

Now I need to undo that, but there is not an option to remove it.  I have unchecked "Run as Administrator."  When I run the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter, it says "Troubleshooting has completed.  No changes or Updates were necessary."  I have no options to uncheck, or deselect.  Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I have done the following:

1. Unpinned Taskbar shortcut
2. Unpinned Start Menu shortcut
3. Opened folder where devenv.exe is located, unchecked "Run as Administrator."
4. Ran "Troubleshoot Compatibility," where no options are available.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill, where in the question does it come across that this is specific to corporate IT?  Pretty sure he just followed the instructions in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1074852/820) and is trying to undo it.

Comment: @heavyd The original wording of the question included reference to changes in his company's IT policy, which is why I think it was put on hold.  Since that was only background info, and not central to the question, I removed those references and voted to reopen.

Comment: @heavyd Then he should say exactly that in his question.

Comment: Should essentially still be the same as here: https://superuser.com/q/309582/219095

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.  I searched myself  and  found the  solution:

1. Troubleshoot  compatibility,  let it detect issues.
2. When done, select "Try Recommended Settings".
3. Press "Test the program..." --> VisualStudio Opens up,  not as administrator.
4. Close Visual Studio.
5. Select --> Yes, save these settings for this  program

Comment: You indicated you performed and searched and found a solution, so what is your source, for this particular solution?